# CSS Animation - change background image after colour change

Tags: css, image, animation

on my site i got this css code

```
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
 0% {color: red; color: lime; color: red;}
 25% {color: lime;}
 50% {color: red;}
 75% {color: lime;}
 100% {color: red;}
}
-webkit-animation: colours 1.5s infinite alternate !important;
```

Every time the color changes can i get it to switch between

```
background-image: url("/images/redshield.png");
```

and

```
background-image: url("/images/greenshield.png"); ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this would keep looping... but something like this should work.

```
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
    0% {
        color: red;
        background-image: url("/images/redshield.png");
    }
    25% {color: lime;}
    50%  {
        color: red;
        background-image: url("/images/greenshield.png");
    }
    75% {color: lime;}
    100% {color: red;}
}

-webkit-animation: colours 1.5s infinite alternate !important;
```